# how can I set an amount of game objects to spawn?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

here is my code and i have no idea how to work it up. im a beginner in c# and this is for our project.
the project is about a balloon popper and i am having trouble to set an amount of balloons to spawn.
I am planning to set the amount of balloons to spawn at 5, 10 even 20 and after that, the spawning will stop.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public GameObject[] balloons;

    public float spawnTime = 0f;
    float spawnTimeLeft = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Update()
    {
        if (spawnTimeLeft >= spawnTime)
        {
            int randBalloon = Random.Range(0, balloons.Length);
            int randSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

            Instantiate(balloons[randBalloon], spawnPoints[randSpawnPoint].position, transform.rotation);
            spawnTimeLeft = 0f;
        }
        else
        {
            spawnTimeLeft = spawnTimeLeft + Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable to the class for the maximum amount. Have done this as `public` so you can set it in the inspector to the amount you wish.

Also add a counter variable and set it to `0`. This is private as nothing but this class needs access to it. Do serialize this field.

```cs
public int spawnAmountMax = 5;
[SerializeField]
private int spawned = 0;
```

---

Start the `Update()` with the next check, return from the method when it evaluates to true.

```cs
if (spawned >= spawnAmountMax)
    return;
```

---

Than after instantiating the GameObject, increase the variable:

```cs
spawned++;
```

---

**The adjusted code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement.TaskbarClock;

public class SpawnScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int spawnAmountMax = 5;
    private int spawned = 0;

    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public GameObject[] balloons;

    public float spawnTime = 0f;
    float spawnTimeLeft = 0f;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Update()
    {

        if (spawned >= spawnAmountMax)
            return;

        if (spawnTimeLeft >= spawnTime)
        {
            int randBalloon = Random.Range(0, balloons.Length);
            int randSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

            Instantiate(balloons[randBalloon], spawnPoints[randSpawnPoint].position, transform.rotation);
            spawnTimeLeft = 0f;

            spawned++;

        } else
        {
            spawnTimeLeft = spawnTimeLeft + Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi thankyou. the code that you add is what im looking for. thankyou and it works!!

Comment: You're welcom. Besides accepting you could up-vote the answer too. This is not for me gaining reputation but that it does. It's about questions and answers which are good will and up higher in the search. That's how SO works and 'we' are sensitive about this system. Also it would tell all you've said in your comment. SO is business, not a chatboard ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnScript: MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;
    public GameObject[] balloons;

    public float spawnTime = 5.0f;
    public float maxSpawnTime = 20.0f;
    
    private void Start()
    {
        Invoke(nameof(Spawn), spawnTime); //This will start the spawning process after the initially set spawnTime, so first this will wait for 5 seconds.
    }
    
    private void Spawn()
    {
        int randBalloon = Random.Range(0, balloons.Length);
        int randSpawnPoint = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

        Instantiate(balloons[randBalloon], spawnPoints[randSpawnPoint].position, transform.rotation);
        
        spawnTime *= 2; //doubles the spawnTime, according to your request, so the second time this will be 10, and the third time, this will be 20 seconds
        if (spawnTime <= maxSpawnTime) //check if we reached or not the maximum spawn time
        {
            Invoke(nameof(Spawn), spawnTime); //if we not yet reached the maximum spawn time, it will start to wait and spawn one more balloon again.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

since you're doing this in you update, you can add a counter after your Instantiate call.

```
    Instantiate(balloons[randBalloon], spawnPoints[randSpawnPoint].position, transform.rotation);
    counter++;
```

And then, nest your if statement inside another if checking for the counter.

```
   if(counter < amountToSpawn)
   {
      //your code here
   }
```

For me personally, I would make a Coroutine method with delay that will have a for loop inside, rather than doing this in update.

Sample:

```
private IEnumerator SpawnObjects(int spawnCount)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < spawnCount; i++)
   {
      //Instantiate here
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
   }
}
```

To call the method:

```
StartCoroutine(SpawnObjects(10));
```